# How to prevent Provider from dispose model?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

On app homepage I set up `Model2` which make API call for data. User can then navigate to other page (`Navigator.push`). But I want make API call from `Model2` when user press back (`_onBackPress()`) so can refresh data on homepage. When I make call, it give error:

> Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct
>   Provider above this Consumer Widget

If I add `Consumer` to Page2 it give error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
>   Consumer Widget

`StatefulWidget` in homepage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>

...
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(context: context)),
```

In Page2:

```
  final context;

  Page2State({Key key, this.context});
...

//    Consumer<Model2>(
//    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
    ...
          onWillPop: () => _onBackPress(context),
...

Future<void> _onBackPress(context) async {

final model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);

  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return 


    Provider.value(value: model2, child:


AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Back'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Go back'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () async {
await model2.getData();

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Again, you need to add your providers to the `navigator.push` builder.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks!! But I am already push context in         `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. you still need to include the necessary providers

Comment: @RémiRousselet Issue is `Model2` is only initialised for some users. Other user group not have `Model2`. But if I call final `model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);` for user who not have `Model2` initialise, it give error

Comment: @RémiRousselet Still have same error when pass in context with:  `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(context: context))`. I have update code above

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit hacky, but overriding the `dispose()` method on your model/provider classes seems to work.

---

E.g., if you have a viewmodel offered as a provider to your view:

```dart
class View extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      lazy: false,
      create: (context) => ViewModel(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
...
}
```

```dart
class ViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
...
  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void dispose() {}
}
```

This will stop the model from being automatically disposed by the provider mechanism. Of course now you have a useless `dispose()` method, so you might need to implement some other method that calls `super.dispose()` to free resources when needed:

```dart
  void myDispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```